# Docker problem connection to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, docker, pdo

I start with docker, and I want to connect to my database using the PDO driver.
But unfortunately, I have an error that appears on my page and I do not know how to solve it.
Can you help me please ?

Here is my error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO :: __ construct ():
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated
>   with hostname

Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=db:3306;dbname:DockerProject', "root", "root");
?>
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: DockerProject
      MYSQL_USER: devuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: devpass
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  web:
    image: php_pdo:latest
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  myadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    links:
        - db:db
```

Comment: `port` is a __separate__ option in dsn-string.

Comment: I try host=db:3306 and i have the same error

Comment: Just `host=db;`

Answer (score 2):

Define [dsn](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) as

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=db;dbname=DockerProject', "root", "root");
```

If you need to define a port **explicitly**, use:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=db;port=3306;dbname=DockerProject', "root", "root");
```

Also, not sure why `dbname:DockerProject` works as correct syntax is `dbname=DockerProject`.